# How do I configure a virtual server in nginx to listen only on IPv6

Tags: nginx, ip, configuration

For my website I need effectively 3 domains:

- example.domain: accessible via both IPv4 & IPv6
- ipv4.example.domain: accessible via IPv4 **only**
- ipv6.example.domain: accessible via IPv6 **only**

I tried to solve this using the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off default_server;
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.domain;
}

# IPv4 only endpoint
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ipv4.example.domain;
}

# IPv6 only endpoint
server {
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name ipv6.example.domain;
}
```

But this throws the error: `nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:80` for the IPv6 server block (line 15 in my example).

How can I achieve the desired result? Would I be required to use 2 separate IPv6 addresses to host these websites on?

Comment: to be easy said, you all just say listen to port 80 regarless so to bind port 80 on ip4 you will exlusive needed to use 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: @djdomi ipv4 isn't the issue, it's IPv6 which throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `listen` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) about the `ipv6only` option:

> This parameter is turned on by default. It can only be set once on
> start.

You cannot use both `ipv6only=off` and `ipv6only=on`.

In fact, your first `server` block should be `ipv6only=on` anyway, because you have separate `listen` directives in the same `server` block, one for ipv4 only, and one for ipv6 only (which is what that option is for).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I understand where my thinking went wrong, this makes total sense. Only odd thing left is that any requests to `ipv6.example.domain` still return a IPv4 address if I check the `REMOTE_ADDR` header. Guessing that might be something docker related.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the `ipv6Only` listen flag, if it is set to `off`, you get a dual-stack socket, while if it is set to `on` it makes an IPv6 socket

You need the following config:

```
server {
    # listen on IPv6 only
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    # listen on IPv4 only
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.domain;
}

# IPv4 only endpoint
server {
    # listen on IPv4 only
    listen 80;
    server_name ipv4.example.domain;
}

# IPv6 only endpoint
server {
    # listen on IPv6 only
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ipv6.example.domain;
}
```

If a request comes in on the `[::]:80` server socket, NGINX knows it has to match to the servers `ipv6.example.domain` or `example.domain`, falling back to `example.domain` if there is no match.